# How to automatically show Title of the Entries/Articles in the Browser Title Bar in ExpressionEngine 2?

Tags: expressionengine

How would I output the title of an entry in ExpressionEngine and display it in the browser's title bar?

Here is the content of my page's header:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{stylesheet=site/site_css}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
```

What I need is for each page to display the title of the entry in my browser's title bar — how can I achieve that?

---

### Part of UPDATED Code:

Here is how i have done it :

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news_articles" status="open|Featured Top Story|Top Story" limit="1" disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination"}

{embed="includes/document_header" page_title=" | {title}"}

<body class="home">
<div id="layoutWrapper">
    {embed="includes/masthead_navigation"}
    <div id="content">
        <div id="article">
            <img src="{article_image}" alt="News Article Image" />
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <h5><span class="by">By</span> {article_author}</h5>
            <p>{entry_date format="%M %d, %Y"} -- Updated {gmt_edit_date format="%M %d, %Y"}</p>                    
            {article_body}    
{/exp:channel:entries}
        </div>
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to show just the name of your ExpressionEngine site (as defined in CP Home > Admin > General Configuration) use the [site name global variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#var_site_name):

`<title>{site_name}</title>`

If you want to display just the current entry title from a given channel use the following:

```
<title>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}
        {title}
    {/exp:weblog:entries}
</title>
```

Many Web Developers will use an [Embed Variable with an Embedded Template](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding_templates.html) to pass the `{entry_title} to a global embed template, allowing for a [dynamic page title](http://expressionengine.com/archived_forums/viewthread/99480/):

```
{embed="includes/header" title="{exp:channel:entries channel="{channel_name}"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}"}
```

If you're using EE2, the [SEO Lite Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/seolite/) takes care of all the hard work for you with a single line of code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {exp:seo_lite url_title="{url_title}"}
</head>
```

Other solutions include the [Low Title Plugin](http://loweblog.com/software/low-title/) *(EE1, EE2)*.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Im going down the embed variable way. Is using Low Title or SEO Lite, better compared to using embed variables, performance wise ?

Comment: Each embed requires a query and an iteration through the ExpressionEngine Template Parser, which can lead to [overhead and performance issues](http://expressionengine.com/blog/entry/troubleshooting_site_performance_issues/). I prefer The SEO Lite Module as I've found it's very "lightweight" and uses only one database query to fetch all of its output. As an added benefit, you get all of the [SEO features included with the module](http://www.addonbakery.com/docs/expressionengine/SEO_Lite_-_Installation_Usage.html).

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely look into SEO lite module. Do you think its enough or should i purpose NSM Better Meta http://ee-garage.com/nsm-better-meta

Comment: How would i use SEO lite to display " Site Name | Article Name " and "Site Name | Category Name" ?

Answer (score 8):

Another relatively new way to tackle it is using the Stash add-on and a template partials approach.  This method knocks you down to one embed, and has the added advantage of giving you a centralized "wrapper" template - one for each major page layout, basically.  The example below assumes you've simply added custom fields to handle any entry-specific meta data you're looking to inject into the header. With this idea in mind, here's a simplified view of the basic structure I've been applying recently:

**In your template you apply EE tags to determine the logic of what gets sent to the inside-wrapper**

```
{embed="embeds/.inside-wrapper"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" limit="1" dynamic="yes" disable="whatever|you|can|live|without"}

{!-- ENTRY SEO META DATA --}
{exp:stash:set name="entry_seo_title" scope="site"}{cf_channelprefix_seo_title}{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:stash:set name="entry_seo_description" scope="site"}{cf_channelprefix_seo_description}{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:stash:set name="entry_seo_keywords" scope="site"}{cf_channelprefix_seo_keywords}{/exp:stash:set}

{!-- ENTRY/PAGE CONTENT --}
{exp:stash:set name="entry_body_content" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" scope="site"}
Your page content here
{/exp:stash:set}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And then in your wrapper template, which would ultimately contain all your wrapping HTML but could be chunked into snippets. for something like the header since it would be shared with other wrapper templates, for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{exp:stash:get name="entry_seo_title"}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{exp:stash:get name="entry_seo_description"}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{exp:stash:get name="entry_seo_keywords"}" />
</head>

<body>

{exp:stash:get name="entry_body_content"}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of trying out Stash. This would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

One addition to Ryan's embed method (which is definitely the most flexile method): chances are you can wrap most of your page in an `{exp:channel:entries}` tag when viewing an individual entry, avoiding the additional (and expensive) channel:entries call. So it would look more like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" limit="1"}
    {embed="includes/header" title="{title}"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {page_content}
    {embed="includes/footer"}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

NSM Better Meta is a more complete way to pass channel meta data to the  tag.

For smaller sites, I use the **String** plugin.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/string

Very simple syntax.