# Sending an entry_id to an embed in ExpressionEngine

Tags: templates, expressionengine

I'm trying to find a good solution to my page title woes. I've never had a perfect solution for doing them in EE and though I'd finally thought I'd made a breakthrough I've hit a brick wall and hopefully one of you more experienced Expression Engine'ers might be able to help.

Basically what I'm trying to do is, where the entries loop that is feeding in the main content for a page in my template I want to grab that entry_id and feed it to the header file embed. I'm doing this in a way much like this...

```
{embed="main/.header" pre_eid="{entry_id}"}

<div id="content">              
    {exp:channel:entries channel="standard-content" url_title="{segment_1}" limit="1"}

        {preload_replace:pre_eid="{entry_id}"}  

        <h1>{title}</h1>
        {content}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

The intention of this being that the id number gets passed to the header file where I can work my magic. What happens though is that as soon as I call {pre_eid} outside of that entries section it outputs the unparsed tag.

How can I go about sending that entry_id parsed to the header? I understand there is something I'm missing here in terms of parse order, or technique though I know I've seen something similar before on other EE code I've looked at.

Answer (score 2):

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6191603/245264) on this topic may be helpful for you.

Basically, many Web Developers will use an [Embed Variable with an Embedded Template](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding.html) to pass the `{entry_title}` to a global embed template, allowing for a [dynamic page title](http://expressionengine.com/archived_forums/viewthread/99480/):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    {embed="includes/header"
        title="
            {exp:channel:entries channel="{channel_name}"}
                {title}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        "
    }
</head>
```

If you're using EE2, the [SEO Lite Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/seolite/) takes care of all the hard work for you with a single line of code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {exp:seo_lite url_title="{url_title}"}
</head>
```

Another clever solution (/via [Derek Hogue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6192083)) is to wrap most of your page in a single `{exp:channel:entries}` tag on individual entry page templates, avoiding the overhead of using multiple *and expensive* channel entries queries:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" limit="1"}
    {embed="includes/header" title="{title}"}

    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {page_content}

    {embed="includes/footer"}

    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Other solutions include the [Low Title Plugin](http://loweblog.com/software/low-title/) *(EE1, EE2)*.

Answer (score 1):

The `{entry_id}` variable isn't set outside of a channel entries query. You need to include it between the openening and closing `{exp:channel:entries}` tags.

Try something like this instead:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" url_title="{segment_1}" limit="1"}
    {embed="main/.header" pre_eid="{entry_id}"}

    {preload_replace:pre_eid="{entry_id}"}
    ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

---

Incidentally, the `{preload_replace}` template tag variable you're using used to be called `{assign_variable}` in EE1.

[Preload Text Replacements](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html) are evaluated **near the end of template parsing**, so you can't use them to contain bits of EE code.

On the other hand, [Snippets](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/snippets.html) are parsed *near the beginning of template* parsing, so it might be useful to you in other ways.

Lodewijk Schutte's [ExpressionEngine Parse Order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf) *(PDF, 32 KB)* has all the excruciating details.